Diagonalization of Matrix question about Alvaro Cartea Algorithimic and High frequency trading
I'm currently reading the book "Algorithmic and High Frequency Trading" by Alvaro Cartea and 2 others.
I encountered this equation and went down a rabbithole of verifying it.

[some text about how we use the max alpha values to best predict the next price]

if k~ is the eigenvalues diagonal matrix of k, then it should be that k~ = A^-1 * k * A right? But when I derived for k~, I got k~ = AkA^-1.
I'm using the equation from Wikipedia on diagonalization.
I included a question at the end of my paper, could we just use that inverse definition for the eigenvalue diagonal. Is A just P^-1?


Did you figure out the answer to your question? To answer your last question: Yes, you can make this change in the diagonalization equation, however, you are also implicitly doing a change of basis as well (see this section of the Wiki page). What implications this has to the process (if any at all) I do not know.

I did not figure out the answer. Although on the next page the book states the equation properly, as: k = U*k~*U^-1. So yes it is a change of basis, I do not understand the implications of this either. It is apparently so that U = A^-1.
